# Unable to find whether an object exists in an Array Of Objects given object as an input

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am a junior level developer trying to solve a scenario, where i should get an error if we are trying to add an existing object to the array.

Input :

```
 {
  id: "0", 
  name: "sdsd"
}
```

Existing Arrays:

```
[{
  id: "0", 
  name: "sdsd"
 },

{
 id: "1", 
 name: "sds"
}, 
{
 id: "2",
 name: "sdf"
}]
```

I am expecting the function to be something like

findDuplicate(Array, Object) => return true if there is one, else false.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over an array? then you know how to compare each array element properties with the properties of an object and return true if the properties match. If you don't know, I suggest you get familiar with each method of the Array object : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 1):

use the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method, as it will return `true` / `false`. If some of the items match `true` is returned otherwise it will return `false` if nothing matches (your callback must return a truthy/falsey value).

```js
let items = [
  { id: "0", name: "sdsd" },
  { id: "1", name: "sds" },
  { id: "2", name: "sdf" }
]

// Test "name"
console.log(items.some(i => i.name == 'sdsd'))
console.log(items.some(i => i.name == 'dog'))

// Test "id"
console.log(items.some(i => i.id == '0'))
console.log(items.some(i => i.id == '100'))

// Test both "name" and "id"
console.log(items.some(i => i.name == 'sdsd' && i.id == '0'))
console.log(items.some(i => i.name == 'sdsd' && i.id == '100'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array filter and array every like follow:

```js
var exist = [{
  id: "0", 
  name: "sdsd"
 },

{
 id: "1", 
 name: "sds"
}, 
{
 id: "2",
 name: "sdf"
}];
function findDuplicate(array, object){
    var result = array.filter(current=>{
        return Object.keys(current).every(key =>{
            if (object[key] === current[key]){
                return key;
            }
        });
    });
    //console.log(result);
    if (result.length == 0 )
        return false;
    return true;
}
console.log (findDuplicate(exist,{id:"0",name:"sdsdf"}));
console.log (findDuplicate(exist,{id:"0",name:"sdsd"}));
```